# How to use wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 in alpine linux

Tags: python, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, alpine-linux

typing:

```
pdfkit.from_string("hello world", "output.pdf"),
```

then get the following:

> IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code -6. error:
>   QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Comment: Describe your problem properly

Comment: Hey you can follow this:
[link](https://github.com/LoicMahieu/alpine-wkhtmltopdf)

It looks like testing wkhtmltopdf package for Alpine still buggy since it's not generating pdfs correctly ...